# microsoft SQL Server stored procedure with loop in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I´m trying to execute a stored procedure from PHP. The EXEC statment is Ok, It runs ok with other procedures, but the issue appears when I put a loop in my stored procedure. I can´t get error but i can´t get results. If I delete the loop from the stored procedure it runs Ok. 
Here is my code:

--STORED PROCEDURE --

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO



ALTER PROCEDURE  [myProcedure]  
    @nivel INT,
    @numPreguntas INT
    as 
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @cont INT
    DECLARE @cadena VARCHAR(500)

CREATE TABLE #TEMPORAL
(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nivel] [int] NULL,
    [tipoPregunta] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [enunciado] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [respuesta1] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [respuesta2] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [respuesta3] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [respuesta4] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [respuesta5] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [respuestaCorrecta] [int] NULL
)

        SET @cont = @nivel  

        WHILE @cont < 3 
        BEGIN  

            INSERT INTO #TEMPORAL
            SELECT top(2) id, nivel, tipoPregunta, enunciado, respuesta1, respuesta2, respuesta3, respuesta4, respuesta5, respuestaCorrecta
            FROM market_stall_empire_preguntas WHERE nivel = @cont ORDER BY NEWID()

            SET @cont = @cont + 1
        END 

set @cadena = 'SELECT id, nivel, tipoPregunta, enunciado, respuesta1, respuesta2, respuesta3, respuesta4, respuesta5, respuestaCorrecta  
FROM #TEMPORAL
ORDER BY NIVEL'

exec (@cadena)

DROP TABLE #TEMPORAL

END
```

-- PHP --

```
$tsql_callSP = "{call myProcedure( ?, ? )}";

$params = array(array($nivel, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($numPreguntas, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN));

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql_callSP, $params);

if ($stmt === false)
{
    echo json_encode(array("SQL Error" => sqlsrv_errors()));
}
else
{
    $data = array();

    $next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($stmt);
    if( $next_result )
    {
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))
        {
            $data[] = array("aaa" => $row[1]);
        }
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt );
    sqlsrv_close( $conn );

    echo json_encode( $data );
}
```

Please help!

Comment: what kind of error? have you try to excecute your SP with loop in SSMS?

Comment: In SSMS the stored procedure runs ok. The problem is that I cant get an error from PHP or SQL